# a question about the cauchy proof of Inequality of arithmetic and geometric means in wikipedia

Tags: inequality

the original text of wikipedia is:

"We then have:

: 
\begin{align}
\alpha & = \frac{x_1 + x_2 + \cdots + x_n}{n} \\[6pt]
& = \frac{\frac{m}{n} \left( x_1 + x_2 + \cdots + x_n \right)}{m} \\[6pt]
& = \frac{x_1 + x_2 + \cdots + x_n + \frac{(m-n)}{n} \left( x_1 + x_2 + \cdots + x_n \right)}{m} \\[6pt]
& = \frac{x_1 + x_2 + \cdots + x_n + \left( m-n \right) \alpha}{m} \\[6pt]
& = \frac{x_1 + x_2 + \cdots + x_n + x_{n+1} + \cdots + x_m}{m} \\[6pt]
& > \sqrt[m]{x_1 x_2 \cdots x_n x_{n+1} \cdots x_m} \\[6pt]
& = \sqrt[m]{x_1 x_2 \cdots x_n \alpha^{m-n}}\,,
\end{align}

so

$\alpha^m > x_1 x_2 \cdots x_n \alpha^{m-n}$

and

$\alpha > \sqrt[n]{x_1 x_2 \cdots x_n}$

as desired."

my question is how did cauchy derive $\alpha^{m-n}$ from $x_{n+1} \cdots x_m$?
It just doesn't make any sense for me........

Comment: You omitted the assumption: $x_{n+1} = x_{n+2} = \cdots = x_m = \alpha$.

Comment: @player3236 sir, could u make this more clear?

Comment: @player3236 I mean, the previous context said  "The case where not all the terms are equal" then how could this assumption still be valid in here?

Comment: The whole proof is by forward-backward induction. Since $n$ is not a power of $2$, we must add more terms to it until it hits $m$, which is some power of $2$, and the result for the power of $2$ was already proven. Also "not all the terms are equal" is not "all terms are not equal".